# How can I do a partial regex search on MongoDB in Korean?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am using MongoDB Atlas to serve my ~110k athlete data.

Each document contains a `name` field and a `korean` field that has the name in Korean that is not supported by MongoDB's Full-Text Search.

I want to implement a query that inputs a korean string like `웨인 루니` and returns all collections with the `korean` data that partially matches (contains the same token as the input string `웨` `인` `etc.`) this query.

I know that the syntax will look like: `{name: {$regex: '<pattern>'}}` in English.

However, I am not sure if this is even possible in Korean.

Thanks in advance.

====EDIT====

Let't say I want to search a document that has `\uc990\ub77c\ud0c4` in its `korean` field. And I want to return the documents that partially match this query (it would return `\uc990\ub85c\ud0c4` and `\uc990\ub77c\ud0d5`- second word and last word differ from the query respectively).

Would this be possible in MongoDB?

Comment: Regular expressions don't care if characters are English or Korean. So the problem is the exact same as running a queries for a couple of roman characters like `'ab'` and returning any record that have an `a` and/or a `b` in them. What have you tried that you think isn't working for Korean?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a transliteration of Korean to ASCII, then use the full-text search capability on the ASCII text.

Comment: @kshetline in that case, do we have to convert the input string into ASCII when we run the query?

Comment: @Grismar, full-text search is more than just matching regular expressions, it tokenizes and indexes text in ways that make searching text a whole lot more efficient than performing a regex match on every single string that you might want to search. I can definitely see how that might not be supported for Korean text in MongoDB.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use the same transliteration on the search strings.

Comment: @kshetline, I get that full-text search is more than regex matching, but it appears that OP is asking about regex matching because full text search does not support Korean characters in their situation. Also, the solution they propose (check if any character appears inside the values of a certain column) is not a description of full-text searching.

Comment: I said Korean is not supported by MongoDB's full-text search because it's not included in the supported language. Before trying to use the regexp search, I used the full-text search for Korean in an unofficial way. In the database, I put the player's name in Korean, like `웨 인 루 니`, and I separated each character by a space to make the full-text search work. And then I also separated the input string by a space to retrieve the documents that has `korean` data that partially match with the input string. However, this causes a memory leak in my server for a long korean string.

Comment: I wanted to find a way to get around this issue. That's the point of asking this question.

Comment: Also, a partial match is very important in this task because, unlike English, the spelling in Korean could vary because there no standard way of writing a non-korean name in Korean.

Comment: @kshetline  I edited my question if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: One thing would complicate searching Korean text is that, although there is a Korean alphabet (hangul), the letters of that alphabet are grouped into syllabic glyphs, and there's a separate Unicode codepoint for each of the possible glyphs. It's those codepoints you have to match on (and also codepoints for hanja, Chinese characters used in Korean). I don't actually know how that's usually solved, I just know enough that I can see that doing it well has got to be tricky.